# Unreal Engine 5 - Keep original pivot point [FBX Import]

Tags: import, export, fbx, unreal-engine5

How can I make UE5 maintain the original pivot point of an object from the 3D software used to create it?

I have absolutely no desire to "eyeball" the locations of hundreds of objects in my archviz project.

I also don't want to export my entire scene as a single FBX file every time I want to make a modification.

I'm using the "Send to Unreal" addon for Blender, which allows you to make modifications to an object and send it to Unreal Engine, where it's updated in the editor immediately.

I have experience using Unity which recognizes the original location of each object and places them accordingly - But in Unreal, when you drag it to the editor window it just moves to the location you dragged it to. Ideally it should move to the location it was in the 3D program.

Is there a hidden feature I don't know about?

Cheers.